# Using service accounts to automate deployments is failing

Tags: openshift, openshift-enterprise

We are trying to automate the build and deployment of containers to projects created in openshift v3.3.  From the documentation I can see that we will need to leverage service accounts to do this but the documentation is hard to follow and the examples I have found in the blogs don't complete the task.  My workflow is as follows with examples oc commands I use:

```
BUILDER_TOKEN='xxx'
DEPLOYER_TOKEN='xxx'

# build and push the image works as expected
docker build -t registry.xyz.com/want/want:latest .
docker login --username=<someuser> --password=${BUILDER_TOKEN} registry.xyz.com
docker push registry.xyz.com/<repo>/<image>:<tag>

# This fails with error
oc login https://api.xyz.com --token=${DEPLOYER_TOKEN} 
oc project <someproject>
oc new-app registry.xyz.com/<repo>/<image>:<tag>

Notice I login into the rest api interface, select the project and create the app but this fails with the following errors:

error: User "system:serviceaccount:want:deployer" cannot create deploymentconfigs in project "default"
error: User "system:serviceaccount:want:deployer" cannot create services in project "default"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Service accounts only have permission in their owning project by default.  You would need to grant deployer access to deploy in other projects.

Comment: As you can see the documentation does not go into much detail here https://docs.openshift.org/latest/admin_guide/service_accounts.html.  I should have mentioned that this problem exists on our openshift dedicated platform and I only see the problem when logged in as an ordinary user.

Answer (score 0):

OK so it seems that using a service account to accomplish this is not the best way to go about things.  This is not helped by the documentation.  The use case above is very common and the correct approach is to simply evoke the new-app with the image name and corresponding tag:

```
oc new-app ${APP}:${TAG}
```

There is no need to mess around with service accounts.